# Calculate total Uptime and Downtime with hourly aggregation

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8QFM.jpg)

I have a query that return an output with the machine state (_value) and mapValue to classify whether uptime/downtime with a duration (events.duration) for each state transition.

This is working fine, but the issue is: i want to be able to aggregate the total uptime/downtime by hour (or day in future).

I can't simply do a sum as those records highlighted in yellow will not reflect the total duration for that hour.
For example:
record1 01:50:00 Uptime 20s
record2 02:10:00 Downtime 30s

If i want to account the uptime (record1) of the total duration should be split between Hour1 and Hour2. See the sample image (Target Output)

Can you suggest a sample Flux query to achieve the Target Output or perhaps a better way to achieve my objective.